# Smooth transition effect for expandable composite

Tags: java, swt

Is there any way in SWT to achieve a smooth transition effect when expanding/collapsing an ExpandableComposite/Section? If so, can you please give me a few hints? Thank you very much.

Comment: I don't think this is possible with the standard controls.

Comment: That's a bummer :(. Guess i`ll just have to manage without smooth effects. Thank you very much for your answer.